# storeText doesn't work on hidden divs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/ to generate tests as JSON documents, and https://www.npmjs.org/package/se-interpreter to run them during CI.

I am running into what looks like a WebDriver issue - when I call `storeText` on a hidden HTML div, then print the representative variable, it is blank. I confirmed this by removing the `display: none;` css attached to `hidden-user-div`.

[image]

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working as expected, as Webdriver doesn't interact with hidden elements (which has display property as `display: none;`).

If you want to make `storeText` to work, you need to set the display property using JavaScript as below, before executing `storeText` command:

```
document.getElementById('hidden-user-div').style.display='inline-block';
```